# Conditional Average ("Averageifs")

Tags: r

I'm working with a data set that is set up as 6 column set with increasing rows. The headers are

```
Brand, Channel, Date, Metric A, Metric B, B/A
```

Sample data:

```
Brands <- c("Brand A","Brand B","Brand C")
Channels <- (c("Channel A","Channel B","Channel A")) 
MetricA <- c(1:3)
MetricB <- c(1:3)
df <- data.frame(Brands,Channels,MetricA,MetricB)
B/A <- df$MetricB/df$MetricA
df <- cbind(B/A)
```

I'm curious to know how to average the column `B/A` if the `Brand == Brand A AND Channel == Channel B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed this to Brand A and Channel A, since those exist in your example data:

```
df$BdivA <- df$MetricB/df$MetricA
df_sub <- subset(df, Brands=='Brand A' & Channels=='Channel A')
mean(df_sub$BdivA)
```

If you are going to do more complex things like this, the dplyr package is great.  You could use it to calculate the means for all combinations of Brands and Channels like this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(BdivA = MetricB/MetricA) %>% 
  group_by(Brands, Channels) %>% 
  summarize(mean_BdivA = mean(BdivA))
```

Comment: And by the way, you can't assign to something like B/A -- the first line of my code provides a valid alternative.

Comment: Duh, should have remembered the subsetting. Is there an alternative way of doing so without creating new subset? ie: working just as its own calculation versus a new subset? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I too am in the Durham area btw. Just getting started in learning more R. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depending on how you look at it, the dplyr way does everything all in one step.  But the base R way would be: `mean(df$BdivA[df$Brands=='Brand A' & df$Channels=='Channel A'])`

Comment: Good luck!  If you're just starting out, learning dplyr right off the bat is one of the best things you could do.  It's much simpler to write and read data wrangling operations with it since you can chain operations, and it's fast and powerful. http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html